# GIF not appearing correctly on JDialog

Tags: java, image, swing, gif, event-dispatch-thread

Well, I developed a wait screen with a `JDialog`, but it only works when isolated.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 *
 * @author krisnamourtscf
 */
public class TelaDeProcessamento extends Thread {

    private String titulo;
    private String mensagem;
    private JDialog dialog;

    public TelaDeProcessamento(String titulo, String mensagem) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.mensagem = mensagem;
        dialog = new JDialog(new JFrame(), true);
    }



     public static TelaDeProcessamento iniciaTela(String titulo, String mensagem) {
        TelaDeProcessamento tela = new TelaDeProcessamento(titulo, mensagem);

        tela.start();
        return tela;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            dialog.setTitle(titulo);
            dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            dialog.setSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
            dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/4.gif"));
            JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
            imageLabel.setLocation(70, 0);
            imageLabel.setText("         " + mensagem);
            imageLabel.setIcon(ii);

            dialog.getContentPane().add(imageLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dialog.validate();
            dialog.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paraTela() {
        dialog.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TelaDeProcessamento tela=TelaDeProcessamento.iniciaTela("Aguarde....", "isso é um teste");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        tela.paraTela();

    }

}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Although, when I call it from another class, the GIF doesn't appear

Called from another `JDialog` class example

```
this.setTitle(title);
        this.setModal(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        TelaDeProcessamento tela = TelaDeProcessamento.iniciaTela("Aguarde", "carregando dados");
        this.initiateScreenComponets();
        tela.paraTela();
        JTableUtil.addEventosSelecaoBusca(this);
        this.setVisible(true);
```

result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect this is because you are performing your actions outside of the AWT event dispatch thread.  Nearly all Swing and AWT methods must be run only in that thread, not in other threads.  Violating this rule will lead to strange and unpredictable behavior.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.

Comment: thanks @VGR I solved the problem with SwingWorker

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem finding the gif in the path... verify that!!

after trying your code I can confirm that your code must work!
[image]

Comment: It's not a path problem

Comment: Read the comment above, it's probably a Theading issue @Krismorte

Comment: I've tried both and is working... IT must be something related to the path

Answer (score 0):

I don't neet to change my Class just the calling method

the old call

```
@Override
            public void initiate(String title) {
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setModal(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    TelaDeProcessamento tela = TelaDeProcessamento.iniciaTela("Aguarde", "carregando dados");
    this.initiateScreenComponets();
    tela.paraTela();
    JTableUtil.addEventosSelecaoBusca(this);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

the new call

```
       @Override
        public void initiate(String title) {
            this.setTitle(title);
            this.setModal(true);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            procedimentoDeEspera();   
        }

  private void procedimentoDeEspera() {
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                TelaDeProcessamento.iniciaTela("Aguarde", "carregando dados");
                initiateScreenComponets();
                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void done() {
                TelaDeProcessamento.paraTela();
                finalizaTela();
            }


        };

        worker.execute();
    }
```

this link helped me
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/multi-threading-in-java-swing-with-swingworker.html